# Making para-dibromobenzene

Tags: aromatic-compounds

What steps do I need to take to make the compound in the picture from just a benzene ring? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to US Patent 3062899A p-dibromobenzene is the major product of the bromination of benzene with 2 equivalents of bromine at ambient temperature. With catalytic aluminium trihalide this remains the outcome below 40C.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [forum](http://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=29556.0):

> To benzene, (add) $\ce{Br2}$ and $\ce{HOAc}$ to get bromobenzene.
> Then (add) $\ce{ZnBr2}$ to get p-bromobenzene as the major isomer. Or
> from aniline, NBS and $\ce{HOAc}$ to get p-bromoaniline.  Then
> diazotonization of aniline with $\ce{NaNO2}$ and subtitution with
> $\ce{NaBr}$ to get p-bromobenzene.

As the source is a forum, I found it highly unreliable but then I found [a page](https://erowid.org/archive/rhodium/chemistry/bromobenzene.html) which shows the process of synthesis of bromobenzene. It says that the para isomer is formed as a minor by-product and there is also a note on the isolation and purification of the para isomer:

> .....Now distill the crude bromobenzene slowly, rejecting the fraction
> boiling up to 150°C, and collecting that of bp 150-160°C. Yield,
> 28-29g (about 19ml). **A small quantity of crude p-dibromobenzene
> remains in the flask.**
>
> [....]
>
> The p-dibromobenzene formed as a by-product in the above reaction
> usually solidifies when the undistilled residue obtained in the first
> distillation is chilled. It may be isolated by adding about 10ml of
> methylated spirit and some activated charcoal to the flask, boiling
> for a few minutes, and filtering hot. On cooling the filtrate in
> ice-water, crystals of p-dibromobenzene, mp 89°C separate:
> recrystallise a second time if necessary to obtain colourless
> crystals.

There is also [a patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US3062899)(@Waylander) which says that p-bromobenzene can be prepared by using bromine and aluminum trihalide as catalyst.

> In general, the bromination of benzene with two moles of bromine per
> mole of benzene at ambient temperature produces predominantly
> p-dibromobenzene. If the bromination is conducted in the presence of
> an aluminun trihalide catalyst at low temperature, e.g., below about
> 40 C., the para-dibromo isomer is still the principal product.